# jquery slidedown doesn't work after clicking add to cart button

Tags: jquery, cart, slidedown, mouseenter, slideup

Hi I'm working on an eCommerce site and I have a cart which slidesdown whenever the mouse enter the cart div and slides up when leaving. It works on page load, But after I click on my add to cart button the slidedown and slideup doesn't work at all.

Here's the jquery code that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = 0;
    $('.sflnkToggleCartWrpIn').mouseenter(function () {
        $('.sfcartSummaryDetailsWrp').slideDown(500);
        return false;
    });
    $('.sfcartSummaryExpandableWrp').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.sfcartSummaryDetailsWrp').slideUp(500);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        $('.sflnkToggleCartWrpIn').mouseenter(function () {
            $('.sfcartSummaryDetailsWrp').slideDown(500);
            return false;
        });
        $('.sfcartSummaryExpandableWrp').mouseleave(function () {
            $('.sfcartSummaryDetailsWrp').slideUp(500);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

The add to cart button is the `input[type="submit"]`

Comment: You are registering your mouse events inside the click event. Where do you ever disable them? This question would definitely benefit from an example of the HTML too.

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Not enough information provided here to give a good answer, are you redirecting on clicking the shop cart link? Is your webpage a one pager with lots of DOM manipulation or is it a multiple page website with redirects?

Comment: well I'll just direct you to the example product page of the site [link](http://www.skyscapes.biz/designs/single-product/arizona-sand/)